# Update: Querying lists in SharePoint 2013

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint-2013, caml

Revised:

Hi, I have tried some new things trying to correct my code pieces by pieces.

- I have checked with CamlQueryHelper and my camlQuery does load the images I desire

However, I am still having issues getting this image rotator to load properly...

```js
<script>

var subsiteUrl = "site/subsite"

(function($j) {
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(doWorkA, "SP.js");

    function doWorkA() {
        var currCtxA = new SP.ClientContext(subsiteUrl);
        var targetListA = currCtxA.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("rotatorimages");

        var queryA = new SP.CamlQuery();

        queryA.set_viewXml("<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\"Modified\" Ascending=\"FALSE\"></FieldRef></OrderBy><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Featured\"/><Value Type=\"Integer\">1</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>")
  
        listItemsA = targetListA.getItems(queryA);
  
        currCtxA.load(listItemsA);
  
        currCtxA.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));   
    }

    function on QuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
        var listItemEnumeratorA = listItemsA.getEnumerator();
        while (listItemEnumeratorA.moveNext()) {
            alert("Found matching Item! \nTitle=" +
                listItemEnumeratorA.get_current().get_item("Featured"));
        }
    }
 
 function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
            alert("Request failed. " + args.get_message() +
                "\n" + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
 
 $(".slideshow").cycle({
  fx: "scrollUp", 
  speed: 300,
  timeout: 4700,
  random: 1
 });
 
 
})(jQuery);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to remove **;** on line 3 in your query. 
Or is it a copy/past typo?

```js
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml( 
    '<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Featured\'/>';
    + '<Value Type=\'Integer\'>1</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>'
);
```

Update

```
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Featured\'/>' +
    '<Value Type=\'Integer\'>1</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');
```

Comment: unfortunately, that was a copy/paste typo... I think I'm doing something wrong with the structure...

Comment: Did you already tried using different value types? Number, Text

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to build your query using CAML Querybuilder. There is a typing mistake in your query I think.

Comment: Just used the CamlQuery helper tool, and revised the code, but it is still nonfunctional on my page...